# Is the rotational speed of stars at the outside of galaxies larger than their Newtonian escape velocity?

Tags: galaxies, galaxy-rotation-curve

Stars at the outer edge of galaxies orbit faster than expected from Newtonian gravity, if no dark matter is assumed.

Does this mean that the stars orbit so rapidly that their orbital speed is even higher than their calculated escape velocity? (Assuming that dark matter is neglected.) The escape velocity is sqrt(2) times the orbital speed (for circular orbits).

In other words: is the orbital speed of the outer stars more than 41.4% higher than expected?

Comment: Yes this is correct.

Comment: Would you have a reference?

Comment: Hi!Have a good day! https://ed.ted.com/lessons/dark-matter-how-does-it-explain-a-star-s-speed-don-lincoln